# What Exception to throw if (arg1 > arg2) should be fulfilled?

Tags: java, exception

I do not really have a problem to solve, I would just like to know if there is a common way to deal with the following:

I have a constructor that takes two arguments (both int). The constructor itself only initializes attributes of my object. However, if `(arg1 > arg2)` is not fulfilled, there will be problems later on. Therefore I want to throw an `Exception` here because this is the place where a potential problem originates.

Is there a common `Exception` to throw in this case? Or would you rather throw a custom `Exception`? If so, how would you call that?

Comment: Sounds like a perfect case for `IllegalArgumentException` to me...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a common `Exception` to throw in this case?

According to [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/IllegalArgumentException.html), an `IllegalArgumentException` can be thrown:

> Thrown to indicate that a method has been passed an **illegal or inappropriate argument**.

---

> Or would you rather throw a custom `Exception`?

It's not the case for throwing own exception unless you already have one and there are a few similar situations where you have thrown it.

Try to answer the following questions, they are gonna point you to the answer:

- Is that an important case to handle?
- Is that a usual validation case?
- Will I encounter similar cases later?

Comment: In addition to the answer.... throwing an "exception" will force the developer to wrap the constructor in a try catch... maybe not what you want in this case...m

Answer (score 1):

This is a good reason to use `IllegalArgumentException`. You can use it in your class that way:

```
class YourClass {
    int first, second;
    YourClass(int first, int second) {
        if(first <= second) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("First argument has to be higher than second, arguments passed: " + first + ", " + second);
        }
        this.first = first;
        this.second = second;
    } 
}
```

Comment: You'll want to give a message indicating what's illegal about the arguments, as well as the actual values given.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I edited my answer and hope now it is a bit more clear.